# ORACLE - concat 2 columns from join in another schema

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table where I store "id" values of employees. Now I need write a Select from that table with concatenation of Name & Surname of that employees. This select  works ok when I do concatenation from same schema:

```
  SELECT NAME || '  ' || SURNAME "Employee"
    FROM Schema1.Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Schema1.Table2 u 
    ON Manager = u.ID
    ORDER BY ID.Table1;
```

But when I do concatenation of same kind of data (same column types and names also) from different schema, I receive **"invalid number"** error in **"u.ID"**:

```
  SELECT NAME || '  ' || SURNAME "Employee"
    FROM Schema1.Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Schema2.Table2 u 
    ON Manager = u.ID
    ORDER BY ID.Table1;
```

Why isn't same Select working in both cases, and what should 2nd Select be like ?
Thanks for help in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad, second schema had a Varchar2 type of something I have Number type in my schema. To_Char solved my problem:

```
SELECT NAME || '  ' || SURNAME "Employee"
    FROM Schema1.Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Schema2.Table2 u 
    ON to_char(Manager) = u.ID
    ORDER BY ID.Table1;
```